# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'adno' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the data from two tables `studentinfo` ans `studentmarks`.

I use `Join`s with where clause but it will show:

```
ConstraintViolationException: Column 'adno' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Here is my code snippet

```
String adno = jTextField10.getText();

String s = "Select si.n,
                   si.class,
                   sm.acc,
                   sm.bst,
                   sm.eco from si Left Join sm 
                   ON si.adno = sm.adno 

                   where adno ='" + adno + "';";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good programmer, write pieces of code that are, **Conventional, Readable, Scalable, Commented and Indented.**

In your case, do this,(mainly use **aliases**, and yes si.adno solves it)

```
SELECT si.name,
       si.class,
       sm.acc,
       sm.bst,
       sm.eco 
FROM studentinfo si 
LEFT JOIN studentmarks sm 
ON si.adno = sm.adno 
WHERE si.adno ='" + adno + " //qualifying the where condition
```

Comment: Execute this in the mysql prompt first and check if its working as expected. Replace '" + adno + "'  with a legit adno.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell which `adno` column should be used `WHERE` clause.

Substitute `where adno` with `where studentinfo.adno`